Matlab Optimization Solver not Applying Options or Converging (Genetic Algorithm)
I am using matlab's optimization toolbox to find the maximum of a function I am calculating numerically/do not have a closed form for. My two inputs are arrays of binary values, and a genetic algorithm is selected using matlab's solve function. Beyond the values in the input arrays being 0 or 1, there aren't any constraints. I have confirmed that my function (fn1) runs correctly, so I believe there is an issue with the code presented below. There are two undesirable outputs I have not been able to figure out:

The "solve" call does not use the options I pass in. I have tried a multitude of different options (plot, display, etc.) that I have confirmed work with Matlab's genetic algorithm via the online documentation, but regardless the solver does not enforce them. To make sure they were being passed to the solver, I tried a call not supported by the genetic algorithm, and a flag was thrown.
The problem doesn't converge to a known solution: The problem doesn't converge at all. I can't share the details of the calculation, but there is a verified optimal value it should converge to. The initial conditions are randomized each time, but nothing has worked so far.

Attached is my code!
num_fragments=8;

tmp = rand(num_fragments,1);
input_1=round(tmp);

tmp = rand(size(input_1,1),1);
input_2=round(tmp);

% Create problem
problem = optimproblem("ObjectiveSense","Maximize");


% Create optimization variables
x = optimvar("x",num_fragments,1,"Type","integer","LowerBound",0,"UpperBound",1);
y = optimvar("y",num_fragments,1,"Type","integer","LowerBound",0,"UpperBound",1);

% Define problem objective
obj=fcn2optimexpr(@fn1,x,y)


% Set objective 
problem.Objective = obj;


% Set initial starting point for the solver
initialPoint.x = input_1;
initialPoint.y = input_2;

% Define problem constraints
problem.Constraints = sum(x,1)+sum(y,1) <= 16;

% Set nondefault solver options
%options7 = optimoptions("intlinprog","PlotFcn","optimplotmilp");

% Set nondefault solver options
% Set nondefault solver options
options2 = optimoptions(@ga,'PlotFcn',@optimplotfval)

% Display problem information
show(problem);


%solve(problem,initialPoint, "Options",options2)
solve(problem,initialPoint,"Options",options2)



% Display results
solution
reasonSolverStopped
objectiveValue


I have tried using same syntax/format shown in the generated code from matlab's optimization app, and from the solve functions documentation page. I was expecting a plot of the desired function/the options to apply in general.
